# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) php

Tags: dpkg, php

```
root@hex:~# apt-get purge php
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'php' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  php-common php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-fpm php7.0-json php7.0-opcache
  php7.0-readline
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up php7.0-common (7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-json:
 php7.0-json depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-json (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-opcache:
 php7.0-opcache depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-opcache (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-readline:
 php7.0-readline depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-readline (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-cli:
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-json; however:
  Package php7.0-json is not configured yet.
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-opcache; however:
  Package php7.0-opcache is not configured yet.
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-readline; however:
  Package php7.0-readline is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-cli (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-fpm:
 php7.0-fpm depends on php7.0-cli; however:
  Package php7.0-cli is not configured yet.
 php7.0-fpm depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.
 php7.0-fpm depends on php7.0-json; however:
  Package php7.0-json is not configured yet.
 php7.0-fpm depends on php7.0-opcache; however:
  Package php7.0-opcache is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-fpm (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 php7.0-common
 php7.0-json
 php7.0-opcache
 php7.0-readline
 php7.0-cli
 php7.0-fpm
```

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, and add the output of that command to the question. However, [read about formatting first](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: The error output often has steps included in it's output for how to resolve many problems.  Did you perform this suggestion from your message output: `sudo apt autoremove`?  It might not resolve all the problems, but it will clean up some of the output that will make the subsequent **install** or **remove** commands cleaner for the next steps to take.